# ¿Tienen sentido las primeras líneas fichero principal módulo PrestaShop?

Tags: php, prestashop

Las primeras líneas del fichero principal de un módulo PrestaShop 1.6-1.7 antes de la declaración de la clase parece que cumplen una función de seguridad:

```
<?php
if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_'))
  exit;
```

Evitar una acceso y ejecución directa del módulo, ya que la constante siempre esta definida en PrestaShop, según la documentación oficial. Lo estaba leyendo y me parecía la cosa más tonta del mundo porque solo hay que definir la constante antes de cargar el fichero del módulo. ¿O estoy equivocado?

Answer (score 0):

Que un módulo sea compatible con tu versión actual de prestashop es muy importante, ya q sino podria causarte un mal funcionamiento o algo peor en la tienda.

La variable _PS_VERSION_ se encuentra definida en /config/autoload.php. Supongo q nadie debe editar o borrar eso, pero por si acaso, que hay de todo en el mundo, el modulo lo comprueba.

Por tanto ante la duda q el modulo sea compatible, por no estar definida la variable, se opta a no istalar el modulo.

Me parece algo muy correcto y para nada tonto por parte de prestashop

Comment: No dice la documentación que esas líneas estén hay por si alguien borra esa constante, dice que esa constante esta siempre definida en PS, y por eso se utiliza como un seguro, para que el módulo no se ejecute de forma directa, lo que como medida de seguridad es muy fácil de saltar, aunque habría que definir otras cosas, crear un autoload... pero esa ya es otra historia.

Comment: ..."esa constante esta siempre definida en PS, y por eso se utiliza como un seguro, para que el módulo no se ejecute de forma directa".... y no habia dicho yo lo mismo? :)